# Different result when querying PostgreSQL through CLI vs through Node.js server

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

I have a simple node.js server that accepts requests & queries a database. When I try to query all balances using the following function

```js
const Pool = require('pg').Pool;
const pool = new Pool({
  user: 'myUsername',
  host: 'localhost',
  database: 'myDatabase',
  password: 'myPassword',
  port: 5432,
});

const getBalances = (request, response) => {
    pool.query('SELECT * FROM balances', (error, results) => {
      if (error) {
        throw error
      }
      response.status(200).json(results.rows)
    })
};
```

I get the following result (ignore the balances, the relevant part dates)

```
[{"balance":400,"last_received":"2020-06-20T22:00:00.000Z"},
{"balance":200,"last_received":"2020-06-20T22:00:00.000Z"}, 
{"balance":200,"last_received":"2020-06-20T22:00:00.000Z"}, 
{"balance":400,"last_received":"2020-06-20T22:00:00.000Z"}]
```

This is odd, as the last_received should point to today's date. When I check this using the PostgreSQL CLI, I get the following result using the same query as in the node.js code:

```
balance | last_received 
--------+--------------
 400    | 2020-06-21
 200    | 2020-06-21
 200    | 2020-06-21
 400    | 2020-06-21
```

The Date is not the same, and it doesn't return the time as when I query using node.js either. The date datatype I used for creating the table is the standard DATE datatype from PostgreSQL. Why is this and how do I resolve this?

What I've tried:
I've tried re-querying and restarting both multiple times to be sure it's not some sort of timing error, but each time the same result and I've queried `show timezone` and gotten the same result on both ends.

Additionally, when querying  `select now()` I get the correct and same date on both views, yet when I query `select CURRENT_DATE` they are different by a day, indicating the problem lies somewhere with the CURRENT_DATE keyword.

Comment: Update: I've noticed this is not just a one-time thing, every new date I insert over the CLI comes out as one day before through the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

node-postgres [converts `Date` types to `Datetime` in the local timezone](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/818), so it's converting to your server/node timezone.

So, either adjust the dates after fetching them, adjust your server/node timezone, or [override the type parser](https://github.com/brianc/node-pg-types).

Comment: As a personal opinion, I'd like to say that I think the library is wrong in doing this and should simply return a Date type.

Comment: I definitely agree with you - Thank you so much for your answer!